# Selecting distinct values by looking at minimum date of a date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to add something to my existing query that would filter out any sales/purchases that occur more than once by only taking the minimum date value.

I've tried using a MIN() function and a GROUP BY operator, but doing that does not allow me to select the other columns I need and this is suppose to be a VIEW that I am pulling into POWER BI.

EDIT: Okay I think I figured it out.  I just use MIN() function and GROUP BY clause, however I have not used the GROUP BY clause before and I am scared that it is going to filter too many rows out.  I need all of the columns that are listed below.  I have also added sample data to play with.  I need to filter out the "duplicate" ContractPurchaseID's by looking at PaymentDue and only selecting the first one.  What are the dangers of using GroupBY?

Sample Data:

```
PurchaseLogID   StoreID     UserID      ContractPurchaseID  PackageName         PurchaseDate    PaymentDue  PurchaseAmount  EverGreenPrice
118849930       7306        48938416    7825299             Monthly Unlimited   2/11/2019       2/11/2019   84              109
118849935       7306        48938416    7825299             Monthly Unlimited   2/11/2019       3/11/2019   109             109
118404876       6700        22920416    6610879             Monthly Unlimited   3/1/2019        3/1/2019    119             119
118746691       6700        23081863    6240459             Monthly Unlimited   3/1/2019        3/1/2019    159             159
118271837       7308        48668745    7777689             8 Pack Monthly      3/1/2019        3/1/2019    89              89
118271747       7308        48668763    7777679             8 Pack Monthly      3/1/2019        3/1/2019    89              89
```

Query:

```
SELECT P.PurchaseLogID, 
    P.StoreID, 
    P.UserID, 
    P.ContractPurchaseID, 
    P.PackageName, 
    P.PurchaseDate, 
    P.PaymentDue, 
    P.PurchaseAmount, 
    C.EvergreenPrice 
FROM PurchaseLog AS P
INNER JOIN ContractPurchases AS C 
    ON P.ContractPurchaseID = C.ContractPurchaseID
INNER JOIN Users AS U 
    ON C.UserID = U.UserID
WHERE P.PaymentDue >= DATEADD(Day, -1, getdate()) 
    AND P.PaymentDue <= DATEADD(Day, +30, getdate())
    AND P.Deleted IS NULL
    AND (P.PaymentDue < C.CancelOn OR C.CancelOn IS NULL)
    AND P.PurchaseAmount <> '0'
    AND (haspastdue IS NULL OR haspastdue = 0)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()` window function

```
select * from
(
SELECT P.PurchaseLogID, P.StoreID, P.UserID, P.ContractPurchaseID, P.PackageName, P.PurchaseDate, P.PaymentDue, P.PurchaseAmount, C.EvergreenPrice,row_number() over(partition by P.PurchaseLogID, P.StoreID, P.UserID, P.ContractPurchaseID order by P.PaymentDue) as rn
FROM PurchaseLog AS P
INNER JOIN ContractPurchases AS C ON P.ContractPurchaseID = C.ContractPurchaseID
INNER JOIN Users AS U ON C.UserID = U.UserID
WHERE P.PaymentDue >= DATEADD(Day, -1, getdate()) AND P.PaymentDue <= DATEADD(Day, +30, getdate())
AND P.Deleted IS NULL
AND (P.PaymentDue < C.CancelOn OR C.CancelOn IS NULL)
AND P.PurchaseAmount <> '0'
AND ( haspastdue IS NULL OR haspastdue = 0)
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: Row_number() would simply select the first row would it not?  Let me clarify what I want.  Out of the data above I would need every row EXCEPT the second row because the ContractPurchaseID is the same in ROW 1 & 2, but the PaymentDue date is higher in row 2 so I want to exclude just that row.